# Response body blank when using HttpClient POST WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am having some issues with HttpClient POST on my windows phone app. Using the following code only returns the headers, but not the json response body that i need.

```
        FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key", apiKey)
        });

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(loginUrl, formContent);
```

Comment: Just a guess, but are you sure that the apiKey is prose to part of KeyValuePair?  Check your Api documentation again.  I would venture a guess that it prose to be the .Headers  instead.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be. The documentation shows it in the query string. `https://api.hockeystreams.com/Login?username=<username>&password=<password>&key=<api_key>` [link](https://www6.hockeystreams.com/api)

Comment: k, if everything is good. Then you need to actually read the data.  Like this `string response_data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: np, I will write it as an answer with description.  Please mark as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(loginUrl, formContent);
```

will only return you a `HttpResponseMessage`, you will need to read the content from it like so to get the JSON/XML data.

```
string response_data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Now `response_data` will equal what you are looking for.